# What is the difference between C++ and Visual C++ and how to start with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ide

So I want to start learning how to make real games and programs, and I bumped into C++ but then I realized that there is also Visual C++. If there's any difference - tell me what it is. If you have any suggestions on how to start in general with C++ program making (not that black window), please let me know.

I just want a cool program to run code on (still don't know any IDEs for C++), and want to start coding real hardcore programs.

Thank you for all the answers in advance!

Comment: Visual C++, or GCC or Clang are (or have) a C++ compilers. They tend to follow the standardized C++ language. Each compilers has also its own extensions. You can compile using a command line with the visual c++ compiler too, using the IDE is not required.

Comment: Do you have an example or video on how to do all of that because I really new to this.

Comment: I don't really know how to start all of this.

Comment: For the gcc toolchain on windows, [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) is realy complete. Hope it is not scary because it also involves basic command lines that are specific to posix os.

Comment: The black window (aka the console) is the correct place to start. Programming is difficult and C++ is probably the most difficult language there is. Getting a good grounding writing small programs in a simple environment is the best way to learn.

Comment: Start by reading a good book or 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: C++ is a computer programming language, and there are different versions of that language dependent on the ISO standard (C++ 03, C++ 11, C++ 14, etc). Visual C++ is a program/compiler from Microsoft that enables you to write programs in C++. Differing versions of Visual C++ have differing levels of implementation conformance to each different C++ standard version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to start coding and learning C++ I would recommend you to watch a bunch of tutorials, maybe even read a book about it. But the best way to learn coding is, to code. Write as many little programs as you can. Get used to the programming language, try out new things. Write useless programs noone needs. 
It sounds like you are very new to all of this and in my opinion it could be to complicated to learn writing "real hardcore programs" in a short time. If you are not willing to put some effort into this you'll probably never write any "real hardcore programs". It is'nt as easy as you may think. You will have to learn a lot of things and it will probably take a while. But once you learned the basics it'll be fun to write your own programs etc..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @vveil answer:

Learn to think or write out what your program should do before writing any code. Even for smaller programs. You can check against you set goals if your coding was successful. Maybe come up with a sketch for more complicated programs (when it comes to inheritance).   And you train to think before writing anything.

If you are really into it there are plenty of playful tutorials ([learn-cpp](https://www.learn-cpp.org/de/)) out there where the code quest is provided and you try to solve it. Sometime you can code online and do not have to bother about toolchain and environment.

Most important: Have fun!